# Reasoning about Schnirelmann Density: Proving that $d(C) \ge d(A) + d(B)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, analytic-number-theory, additive-combinatorics, supremum-and-infimum

I am taking this argument from Gelfond & Linnik's Elementary Methods in the Analytic Theory of Numbers.

They state if for every $n \ge 1$, there exists $m \in [1,n]$ where $C(n) - C(n-m) \ge (d(A) + d(B))m$, then it "may be deduced from it without difficulty" that $d(C) \ge d(A) + d(B)$

Here's the reasoning presented:

(1)  Assume that for every $n \ge 1$, there exists $m \in [1,n]$ such that $C(n) - C(n-m) \ge (d(A) + d(B))m$

(2)  Consider the segment $[1,n-m]$

(3)  Then, it follows that a segment $[n - m - m' + 1, n - m]$ can be found where $C(n-m) - C(n-m-m') \ge (d(A)+d(B))m'$

(4)  We can extract from $[1,n-m-m']$ the "extreme right-hand segment with the same property then continue our argument."

(5)  "As a result we obviously arrive at the inequality": $d(C) \ge d(A) + d(B)$

This might be obvious to the others.  I'm still scratching my head.  If we can make the size of $m$ as small as we want, why would this prove that $d(C) \ge d(A) + d(B)$.

It would help me to understand the argument if someone could explain the principle that lets us reach the conclusion intended.

Here's my understanding of Schnirelmann Density.

- $A,B$ are infinite sequences of integers starting with $0$ with in sequential order such as $0, a_1, a_2, \cdots$ where $0 < a_1 < a_2 < \cdots$
- Schnirelmann density is defined as:
  $$d(A) = \inf\limits_{n}\frac{A(n)}{n}$$

where: $$A(n) = \sum\limits_{0<a_i\le{n}}{1}$$

- So, it is clear that:  $$0 \le \frac{A(n)}{n} \le 1$$
- $C = A+B$ where $+$ is the [sumset](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sumset).

Comment: In the inequality in (3), should it be $m^\prime$ on the right hand side?

Comment: "...there exists $m \in [1,m]$" involves a typo, doesn't it?

Comment: Yes, you are right.  There's a typo.  It should read:  $C(n-m) - C(n-m-m') \ge (d(A)+d(B))m'$.  I'll fix that.

Comment: @MatthewConroy, that's right.  It should read "there exists $m \in [1,n]$.  I'll fix that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As we repeat the argument on ever-smaller segments, we get:
$C(n) - C(n-m) \geq (d(A) + d(B))m$
$C(n-m) - C(n-m-m^\prime) \geq (d(A)+d(B))m^\prime$
$C(n-m-m^\prime) - C(n-m-m^\prime-m^{\prime\prime}) \geq (d(A)+d(B))m^{\prime\prime}$
and so on.  We add these and get the LHS to telescope, so
$C(n) \geq (d(A)+d(B))(m+m^\prime+m^{\prime\prime}+\cdots) = (d(A)+d(B))n$.

Now divide both sides by $n$: $\displaystyle \frac{C(n)}{n} \geq d(A)+d(B)$.  Hence taking the infimum over $n$ the inequality still holds and $d(C) \geq d(A)+d(B)$.

Comment: Thank you very much!  I'll review the reasoning to make sure I am clear and then I'll accept the answer.  I feel much closer to understanding!  :-)